# To prove that the integral of the function lies between the lower darboux sum and the upper darboux sum

Tags: riemann-integration

m = inf(f(x): x is a member of [a,b]), M = sup(f(x): x is a member of [a,b])

suppose that the function is Riemann integrable

Prove the following

$$ m(b-a)\leq {\int_{a}^{b}} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x \leq M(b-a) $$

Therefore what i have done was take the L(P,F) which results in m(b-a) and then i evaluated the U(P,f) which results in M(b-a), therefore since from the question the interval is closed b > a therefore this implies that since the value m is the inf which is the smallest value and the value M is the sup which is the largest value i can conclude that

$$ m(b-a)\leq M(b-a) $$

which shows that the L(P,f) is less than or equal too U(P,f)

This is what  I have done thus far, now what i know is that for the Lower Riemann integral is taken as the sup (L(P,f) where p is a member of a Partition on [a,b]) therefore this value will increase and for opposite inf(U(P,f)) this value will decrease and the point at which both values are equal is known as the integral of the function. Therefore i can understand that the integral exists between the upper and lower sums once the integrals are equal but not sure how to show it can anyone assist.

I was considering using the riemann sum to show that is the limit exists and the function is said to be riemann integrable on the closed interval [a,b] then the limit of the riemann summ = the integral of the fucntion which lies between the upper and lower darboux sums.

Can anyone tell me if i am correct and if so am i on the right track to proving what is required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are definitely on the right track.

Making this precise mathematically, we have for **any** partition $P = (x_0,x_1,\ldots, x_n)$ of $[a,b]$ and $\xi_j \in [x_{j-1},x_j]$ for all $j \in \{1,2\ldots,n\}$,

$$m = \inf_{x \in [a,b]}f(x) \leqslant \inf_{x \in [x_{j-1},x_j]}f(x)\leqslant f(\xi_j)  \leqslant \sup_{x \in [x_{j-1},x_j]}f(x) \leqslant  \sup_{x \in [a,b]}f(x) = M$$

Multiplying by $(x_j - x_{j-1})$ and summing leads to

$$\tag{*}m(b-a) \leqslant L(P,f) \leqslant S(P,f) \leqslant U(P,f) \leqslant M(b-a),$$
where $S(P,f)$ is a Riemann sum with (arbitrary) intermediate points $\xi_j$.

Given the hypothesis that $f$ is Riemann integrable, it must hold with $\|P\| := \max_{1\leqslant j \leqslant n}(x_j - x_{j-1})$ that

$$\tag{**}\lim_{\|P\| \to 0}S(P,f) = \int_a^bf(x) \, dx$$

Together (*) and (**) imply that

$$m(b-a) \leqslant \int_a^b f(x) \, dx \leqslant M(b-a)$$

**More precisely**

For every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that if $\|P\| < \delta$, then

$$\int_a^b f(x) \, dx - \epsilon < S(P,f) < \int_a^b f(x) \, dx+ \epsilon$$

Suppose that $M(b-a) < \int_a^b f(x) \, dx$.  Taking $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2}  \int_a^b f(x) \, dx +\frac{1}{2}M(b-a)$ we would have

$$S(P,f) > \int_a^b f(x) \, dx - \epsilon =  \frac{1}{2}  \int_a^b f(x) \, dx + \frac{1}{2}M(b-a) > M(b-a), $$

a contradiction.

By a similar argument we can show that $\int_a^b f(x) \, dx \geqslant m (b-a).$

Comment: Thank you for answering the question and showing me this precisely I was also wondering for the above result as it relates to the proof can this be also considered $$ m(b-a)\leq sup(L(P,f)) = inf(U(P,f)) \leq M(b-a) $$ since for the fucntion to be riemann integrable the upper and lower integrals has to be equal to each other, therefore is it possible to compare the relationship between the upper riemann integral anfd the upper sum as well as the lower sum and the lower riemann integral as shown can be used to proof that the integral exists between the upper and lower sums ?

Comment: @Amir: That is also valid and clearly a shorter proof. In my answer I wanted to follow your original idea about the limit of Riemann sums.

Comment: no thank you for the clarification i am very much grateful for your assistance in this topic, i understand because i gave mention of the riemann sum i just wanted to ask about this aspect as well since i was wondering if this could of been used as well. Thank you @RRL